# How do I encode characters using UTF-8 in a QR code using Zxing project?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

Zxing Project is a famous open-source, multi-format 1D/2D barcode image processing library implemented in Java, with ports to other languages. But I believe there are somebody have the same problem just like me: I can't Encode UTF-8 characters in a Qrcode.

How do I encode characters using UTF-8 in a QR code using Zxing project?

Comment: Please change this to a *question*, ideally one which is more technically accurate (There aren't "UTF-8 characters" there are "characters which are then encoded in UTF-8 to get a binary representation".) Then answer your own question. Currently this "question" is not a good fit for the site.

Comment: Brilliant, a well-formulated, insightful, deeply researched answer. What was the questions?

Comment: Sorry, this is not a question, I just want to share how solve this problem for others people....what's should I do properly？

Comment: @Bluegray - Edit your questions so it is a question. For example "How do I encode characters using UTF-8 in a QR code using Zxing project?"  Next, add your description of how to do this as an answer below.  This allows people to comment and vote on your answer and also add their own answer if they know of a better/different way to do this.  I could do this for you but the the answer would be in my name and I don't want to take your Rep points!

Comment: @DaveWebb : thank you very much, I'll revise my question.

Comment: Is the problem to have an UTF-8 encoded string in what is scanned, or to put Unicode characters in a QR?

Answer (score 23):

The proper way of doing this is using hints:

```
  Hashtable hints = new Hashtable();
  hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");
```

Then call this version of `encode` in `QRCodeWriter` class:

```
  encode(String contents, BarcodeFormat format, int width, int height,Hashtable hints)
```

Comment: I use the Core.jar of Zxing project, and use your codes correctly, although Qrcode could be generated, but if I use "Qr Droid" or "QuickMark" apps to decode this Qrcode, it can't be decoded.

anyway, thanks your help and answer.:)

Comment: That's because these apps are not using hints for decoding in UTF-8, so it is the expected behavior. If you were writing your decoding app, you could pass the `MultiFormatReader` a hashtable of hints where you have put the desired charset with `DecodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET` as key.

Answer (score 9):

Mister Smith's answer is quite right. But somehow you need to use the lowercase `utf-8` instead of uppercase `UTF-8` when encoding with `ZXing`. Or some scanners such as Alipay cannot read it.

```
Hashtable hints = new Hashtable();
hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "utf-8");
```

Comment: This is very surprising! Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I found there is an API which is easier:

```
.withCharset("utf-8")
```

Example:

```
Bitmap bitmap = QRCode.from([string])
                   .withSize([width], [height])
                   .withCharset("utf-8")
                   .bitmap();
```

Comment: I see `QRCode` but I don't see the `from()` method, where did you get that?

Comment: looks like the QR higher level api not xzing.

Comment: @SamChen its com.github.kenglxn.QRGen